# Emacs CSS mode won't indent values across multiple lines

Tags: css, emacs, indentation, smie

When a line in my CSS file appears to be too long (typically a property followed by a bunch of values), I want to split them in to several new lines like this (sorry for my low reputation):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxXvv.png

But I have to manually enter spaces before the lines to achieve that. In reality, when I hit TAB with my cursor on the `url` line, what I get is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4nxa.png

The worst thing is that, after manually inserting the spaces, when I hit TAB again on the same line, it goes back to the ugly format due to `indent-region`.

This is not a significant issue but it really pains me and I really hope we can have a decent solution here. Thanks in advance!

M-x version:

```
GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0, NS appkit-1504.60 Version 10.12.1 (Build 16B2555)) of 2016-11-27
```

EDIT:
Also tried web-mode for css files and xah-css-mode. None of them worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`css-mode` uses `smie` for indentation.  It looks like the `:` in that scenario is tokenized as ":-property".  One option would be changing the `css-smie-rules` to include another rule for indenting after that token.

Evaluating the following redefinition seems to give the indentation you want,

```
(defun css-smie-rules (kind token)
  (pcase (cons kind token)
    (`(:elem . basic) css-indent-offset)
    (`(:elem . arg) 0)
    (`(:list-intro . ,(or `";" `"")) t) ;"" stands for BOB (bug#15467).
    (`(:before . "{")
     (when (or (smie-rule-hanging-p) (smie-rule-bolp))
       (smie-backward-sexp ";")
       (smie-indent-virtual)))
    (`(:before . ,(or "{" "("))
     (if (smie-rule-hanging-p) (smie-rule-parent 0)))
    ;; *** Additional rule ***
    (`(:after . ":-property") css-indent-offset)))
```

There is the command `smie-config-show-indent` that is useful to determine what indentation rules are being used at a given point.

Comment: Thank you so much for bringing up the `smie` thing. Without your help I would never be able to know these kind of behind-the-scene. Copying & pasting your code didn't immediately solved the problem, but I tried to tweak that snippet a little bit and things finally worked out. Your `smie-config-show-indent` helped a lot as well. Thanks!

Comment: When I use `smie-config-show-indent` it seems that the `:-property` never shows up, all that appears is `:` only. Does that have something to do with version difference?

Comment: @tsktsktsk64 yea, I just checked.  Apparently, that was an addition somewhere between emacs 25 and 26.  So, the above should work if you upgrade to 26 (or just pull the newer `css-mode` into your emacs)

Comment: If you don't mind spending more time on this trivial thing... I've just edited the question, and that's what my way actually gives me when I have more than two lines. I have absolutely no idea how `smie` works and now I'm stuck. I'll try to upgrade to 26... Meanwhile would you please take a look at my current progress?

Comment: @tsktsktsk64 If I were you I would cherry pick [css-mode](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/textmodes/css-mode.el) into your site-lisp. The `:-property` seems to be the ideal solution that you probably dont want to do yourself

Comment: Amazing. Problem solved. Straightforward and elegant. Thank you for helping me all along the way.

Answer (score 0):

<s>@jenesaisquoi mentioned `smie` and provided an example which is really helpful. Here's my maybe-final solution to my own question.</s>

Add these to the `init.el` file:

```
(require 'smie)
(defun css-smie-rules (kind token)
  (pcase (cons kind token)
    (`(:elem . basic) css-indent-offset)
    (`(:elem . arg) 0)
    (`(:list-intro . ,(or `";" `"")) t) ;"" stands for BOB (bug#15467).
    (`(:before . "{")
     (when (or (smie-rule-hanging-p) (smie-rule-bolp))
       (smie-backward-sexp ";")
       (smie-indent-virtual)))
    (`(:before . ,(or "{" "("))
     (if (smie-rule-hanging-p) (smie-rule-parent 0)))
    ;; *** Additional rules below ***
    (`(:after . ":") css-indent-offset)
    (`(:after . ",") css-indent-offset)))
```

The syntax is pretty self-explaining.

Maybe there are some ways to modify a function without re-writing it, but  I'm not familiar with all the advice thing yet, so if I find a more elegant way I'll come back and edit.

Go to jenesaiquoi's answer for the best solution we can have now.

I've opened a issue for `web-mode` in Github, and the author of `web-mode` is now working on it. We will soon see an integrated support for the indentation I mentioned in the question.

Comment: does that give you the indentation you put in the picture?  It doesn't for me but I'm on emacs 26, maybe css package has changed.  The rule could probably be shortened to `\`(:after . ,(or ":" ",") css-indent-offset)`

Comment: @jenesaisquoi To be honest, I'm experiencing problems now. Now I'm diving into parsers and... whatever. I'll try to toy around and take that as a chance to learn...